# ReactJS TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router, push, navigateurl

I build my Apps and learn ReactJS

My code error until now, i try to search on internet and forums but can't fix.
Here my code :

```
logout(){
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    localStorage.clear();
    if(localStorage.getItem('token') === null){
        this.props.history.push('/login')
    }
}
```

Error : **TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**

Please Help Me

Comment: your error message says Cannot read property 'push' of undefined, it means this.props.history is not exist, for debugging first console this.props.history

Comment: can you please share more of your code? like the whole component

Comment: did you wrap your component in a `withRouter` HOC. [example from docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter)

Comment: Hi, props.history doesn't have a value in it.  It's type is undefined right now.  This link may help a little http://net-informations.com/js/iq/unerror.htm

Answer (score 4):

My guess is your `logout` is within a component which is not a Route it self.
By that what I mean is you're not doing `<Route path="/" component={ComponentThatHasLogoutMethod} />`

Only the components that are used as Route has `history` prop.
if you need those in some other nested Component you can use the `withRouter` Higher order component from `react-router-dom`

```js
export default withRouter(ComponentThatHasLogoutMethod)
```

This will pass the history prop to your component and you'll not get null.

Answer (score 2):

Solution Example with react hooks:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  const history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    localStorage.removeItem("token")
    localStorage.clear()
    if(!localStorage.getItem('token')){
      history.push("/login")
    }
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Login
    </button>
  );
}
```

More info you can find in docs
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar issue while creating custom portal to show model like logout/login.

```
const App = () => {
  const [modal] = useSelector(({ modal }) => [modal])
  return (
    <>
      <Portal modal={modal} />  
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Correct way-
Portal must me child of BrowserRouter.

```
const App = () => {
      const [modal] = useSelector(({ modal }) => [modal])
      return (
        <>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Portal modal={modal} />  
            <Routes />
          </BrowserRouter>
        </>
      );
   }
```

For more reference see [Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start).

Answer (score 0):

We have two solutions for this problem -:

- Replace function declaration with fat arrow notation declaration i.e -:

> ```
>   logout = () => {
>         localStorage.removeItem("token");
>         localStorage.clear();
>         if(localStorage.getItem('token') === null){
>             this.props.history.push('/login');
>         }
>     }
> ```

- We can bind `logout` function in the constructor -:

> ```
>   constructor(props){
>       super(props);
>       this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
>   }
> ```